# How to replace ' with \' in python?

Tags: python, replace, character

I want to replace `"'"` with `"\'"` inside the word `"O'Fallon"`.
But when I use the following code:

```
City="O'Fallon"
City.replace("'","\'")
```

I get `"O'Fallon"` as the output and when use this code:

```
City="O'Fallon"
City.replace("'","\\'")
```

I get `"O\\'Fallon"` as the output. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: The double slash is *normal behaviour*. Try `print City.replace("'", "\\'")`.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like `repr(City)` or `pipes.quote(City)` (or `shlex.quote()` on Python >= 3.3), depending on what environment you want to escape your string for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters obviously, that's why the OP thinks their second attempt doesn't work. But my point was: If they have need to escape single quotes, they probably need to escape strings that are going to be interpreted by a specific parser. Maybe Python, maybe a shell, who knows. Sot hey should use a function that properly escapes *every* character with special meaning in the target environment, and not just replace single quotes.

Comment: @LukasGraf: right, I see what you mean. I made a similar comment below, sensing that they are using this in a SQL query somewhere. At which point you'd ask the database driver to do the escaping..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the representation shown in the console.

If you `print` it, you'll see it's all fine.

Comment: I don't want to print it, I want to add it as a part of a query.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's fine.

Comment: @user2079550: the `print` shows you that the value contains just the one backslash, not two. Another way to see this is to use `result[1:3], len(result[1:3])`, which will produce `("\\'", 2)`. You can use it as part of a query.

Comment: @user2079550: however, if this is part of a *SQL query*, then don't try and escape the values yourself. Leave that to the database driver, use SQL parameters, not string concatenation or interpolation.